# How to locate the ButtonView to the end of the TextView with large singleline text and not move it out of the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have the **Button** at the end of **TextView**:
[image: small text]

When text is increasing, I get the following:
[image: button behind the screen]

But I want that my button locates only at the end of text and doesn't move out of the screen when text is large:
[image: needed result]

This is my layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Long text without button"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="36sp" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:text="Button" />

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

If I move **layout_weight** from **FrameLayout** to **AppCompatTextView** then I get needed result, but with smal text I get the following:
  [image: bad result]

I tried with **LinearLayout** weights and **ConstraintLayout**, but nothing to help me.
How to achieve this?

Comment: means with small text button should be right of textview not at the end of screen right?

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan yes

Comment: Assign fix width:

Comment: @Opriday bad idea, text in the TextView is not static and is changed at the runtime.

Comment: I know but horizontalView can help you in order see full text no matter how much it scale.

Comment: https://www.android-examples.com/scroll-textview-text-horizontally-in-android/

Comment: @Opriday This is not what i need. My problem is not cropping the text, but that the button goes off the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just use `ConstraintLayout`.

### Try this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="0dp" <-- It means using match-constraint.
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Long text without button"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="36sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Button"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/text"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/text"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/text" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

### Result

[image]

### Additional XML - version `wrap_content`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="short text"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="36sp"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Button"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/text"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/text"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/text" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Modify `layout_constraintHorizontal_bias` attributes of **`TextView`** to fit layout you want.

Comment: thanks, but with small text the button always locates on the right of the screen. This is not what i need

Comment: @ilyamuromets Okay, just using `constaraintedWidth`. I'll add additional `xml`.

Comment: yes, with `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"` it works like I need, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this method using Grid Layout and AppcompatTextview hope it helps you.

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

   <GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="1">


          <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
          android:id="@+id/text"
          android:layout_width="200dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
          android:ellipsize="end"
          android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
          android:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
          android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
          android:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
          android:maxLines="1"
          android:layout_columnWeight="0"
          android:text="Long text without button"
          android:textColor="#000"
          android:textSize="20sp" />

          <FrameLayout
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_columnWeight="1">

         <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
         android:id="@+id/button"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:maxLines="1"
         android:ellipsize="end"
         android:text="Button" />
       </FrameLayout>
   </GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thanks, but with small text the button always locates on the right of the screen. And with very large text, it decrease text size. This is not what i need

Comment: but the mobile screen resolution is static so the only choice you have for this is making the text in autosize so it is still readable to your user. btw your welcome.

Comment: My problem is not cropping the text, but that the button goes off the screen. And empty field between text and button is not what i need.